# Differentiate Gameobject colliders with the same tag

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

In my OnTriggerEnter2D() I have a if condition which checks if the right collider is colliding with my other Gameobject. For a simple Example: There is a Lion and a Elephant with the Tag "Animal" with the same script that manages their variables. Based on which of the two Animals enter the other Collider I want to execute specific code.
I tried to give both animals a string which tells which type they are as in Lion is a Lion. But that didnt work.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D a_collider2D)
{

    if (a_collider2D.gameObject.CompareTag("Animal") && m_sAnimalStat.m_sAnimalType.Equals("Lion")) 
    {//code here if its a Lion}
```

Is there another way to tell colliders apart? Putting them on different Layers didnt work out either.
OnTriggerEnter2D is on the other Gameobject where the animals are walking towards. The AnimaStatManager is on the Lion Prefab which has the Tag "Animal". As said it manages various variables for all my animals. Like the m_sAnimalType.
m_aAnimalStat=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Animal").GetComponent(); --> just so i can access what i need from that script.

Comment: Is the OnTriggerEnter2D method on the Animal object? Or the "portal" object?

Comment: The method is on the "portal" Object.

Comment: Where's "m_sAnimalType" coming from? I mean, where is it declared? The way you're referencing it makes me think it's coming from the "portal" object, which makes no sense.

Comment: Oh damn my fault i forgot to type the VariableManager class as where its coming from. I'll edit the question

Comment: There are different ways of doing what you are intending to do. Based on your logic, one quick way is, using the "a_collider2D" parameter to access the Animal object via GetComponent<T>(). 

`var currentAnimal = a_collider2D.GetComponent<Animal>();` and checking if the animal type is what you need to check, e.g Elephant, Cat etc.

Comment: I don't know of any reason why the code that you posted wouldn't work, unless either your tag or `m_sAnimalType` don't actually equal the values you think they do.  Have you tried putting some `Debug` statements in `OnTriggerEnter2D` to see what the tag and animal type values actually are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity objects are defined by *composition*. This means an object is defined by it's *components*.
So, in my opinion, a better approach could be having a "Lion" component on a Lion object, except you have a specific reason not to.

You take your `class Animal : MonoBehaviour` and create a child class for each species: `class Lion : Animal`, `class Elephant : Animal`, etc.

Then, you can simply do:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D a_collider2D)
{
    if (a_collider2D.GetComponent<Lion>() != null) {
        // Lion
    }
    else if (a_collider2D.GetComponent<Elephant>() != null) {
        // Elephant
    }
    else if (a_collider2D.GetComponent<...>() != null) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason i chose to not have a class for each animal is because my other Gameobject is chasing every Gameobject with the tag "Animal" and it seemed nearly impossible to manage so many differently tagged Objects with the Astar project for pathfinding. Although thanks for you answer is will try it out!

Comment: I don't know the Astar project, however you can still keep all of them tagged as "Animal", and store references in code as `Animal` objects, taking advantage of Polymorphism. If you'd like to describe the problem with this approach a little further I'm curious.

Comment: Good idea in principle, but I'd leave out the polymorphism and multiple code files.  Just keep a string or enum inside your ```Animal``` class to track its type.

Comment: Apologies for the late answer!  With a bit of changes the answer from Aboud helped me with the problem! I also had  the problem that a collider from the child element interfered with detecting the parent. But all the comments helped too and are good for using different ways of solving such a problem!